# information protection and block screen capture in flutter desktop?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

Is there any solution in Flutter to prevent screen capture and recording of contents inside the App
i need somthing like Electron's [win.setContentProtection(true);](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winsetcontentprotectionenable-macos-windows) equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Flutter allows you to call platform APIs via [platform channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels), so you can call the same platform APIs described in the documentation you linked to in your question.

You could also [make a plugin](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin) that provides that API, and both publish it for anyone to use, and use the plugin in your own application.

Comment: The link i putted in my question was about Electron's docs not platforms. for windows we have to use SetWindowDisplayAffinity that i tested and its working. im trying to do somthing similar for macos then i'll make a plugin for it.

Comment: I was referring to the description in those docs about how it is implemented: "On macOS it sets the NSWindow's sharingType to NSWindowSharingNone. On Windows it calls SetWindowDisplayAffinity with WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE."